# How can I check for a specific class using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, class

So I need to be able to check if a specified id has a specific class, but I'm not completely sure on how to do that.

Here is my code. You can see my attempt at checking a id for a specific class in the homeTransition function.

```js
function homeTransition()
    {   
        if(document.getElementById("aboutContent").hasClass("animated fadeInUp")){
            document.getElementById("aboutContent").className = " animated slideOutDown";
        } else if(document.getElementById("projectsContent").hasClass("animated fadeInUp")){
            document.getElementById("projectsContent").className = " animated slideOutDown";
            } else if(document.getElementById("contactContent").hasClass("animated fadeInUp")){
                document.getElementById("contactContent").className = " animated slideOutDown";
            }
                    document.getElementById("astronaut").className = " animated fadeIn";
    }

function aboutTransition()
    {   
        document.getElementById("astronaut").className = " animated fadeOut";
        document.getElementById("aboutContent").className = " animated fadeInUp";
        
        document.getElementById("projectsContent").className = " animated fadeOutLeft";
        document.getElementById("contactContent").className = " animated fadeOutLeft";
    }

function projectsTransition()
    {   
        document.getElementById("astronaut").className = " animated fadeOut";
        document.getElementById("projectsContent").className = " animated fadeInUp";
        
        document.getElementById("aboutContent").className = " animated fadeOutLeft";
        document.getElementById("contactContent").className = " animated fadeOutLeft";
    }

function contactTransition()
    {
        document.getElementById("astronaut").className = " animated fadeOut";
        document.getElementById("contactContent").className = " animated fadeInUp";
        
        document.getElementById("aboutContent").className = " animated fadeOutLeft";
        document.getElementById("projectsContent").className = " animated fadeOutLeft";
    }

//Menu
function expand(){
  $(this).toggleClass("on");
  $(".menu").toggleClass("active");
};
$(".button").on('click', expand);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  color: #ccc;
  z-index: -100;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#aboutContent {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 250ms;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
  background-color: #2b2b41;
  z-index: -1;
}

#projectsContent {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 250ms;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
  background-color: #42424b;
  z-index: -1;
}

#contactContent {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 250ms;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
  background-color: #353440;
  z-index: -1;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgba(45, 51, 54, 0.9);
  width: 18%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 250ms;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
  text-align:center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000000;
}

.active {
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0);
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0);
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
  color: #e5e5e5;
}

h1 {
  margin-top:60%;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  cursor: default;
}

ul {
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  font-size:14px;
}

li {
  padding:10px 10px;
}

a {
  text-decoration:none;
  padding:10px 15px;
  color:#fff;
  font-family:"Roboto";
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 300;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: #0dffec;
}

.content {
  position:relative;
  width:300px;
}

.button {
  width:20px;
  height:40px;
  margin:24% 36%;
  padding: 14px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.line {
 width: 40px;
 height: 2px;
    background-color: #fff;
 transition: transform 0.3s ease, background 0.3s ease, opacity 0.3s ease, top 0.3s ease;
}

.line.first {
  transform: translateX(-10px) translateY(22px) rotate(-90deg);
}

.line.second {
  transform: translateX(-10px) translateY(19px) rotate(0deg);
}

.button.on .line.top {
 transform: translateX(-10px) translateY(20px) rotate(45deg);
}

.button.on .line.bottom {
 transform: translateX(-10px) translateY(17px)rotate(-45deg);
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { /* Safari and Chrome */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <title>Home</title>
    
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro|Play|Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.css">
</head> 
<body>
    
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="menu">
      
    <h1>Title</h1>
      
    <ul>
       <div id="home" onclick="homeTransition()"><li><a href="#home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> home</a></li></div>
       <div id="about" onclick="aboutTransition()"><li><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> about</a></li></div>
       <div id="projects" onclick="projectsTransition()"><li><a href="#projects"><i class="fa fa-code"></i> projects</a></li></div>
       <div id="contact" onclick="contactTransition()"><li><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> contact</a></li></div>
    </ul>
  </div>
    
  <div class="content">
    <div class="button">
      <div class="line first top"></div>
      <div class="line second bottom"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
    
    
    
    <div id="aboutContent">
    
    </div>
    
    <div id="projectsContent">
    
    </div>
    
    <div id="contactContent">
    
    </div>
    
</div>
    
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/transition.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/background.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check like this

```
document.getElementById("projectsContent").className.indexOf("animated") !== -1 // class exists on element
```

But for this you can check for only one class, if you want to check for multiple classes store the className in a variable and check for all of them or write a utility function.

EDIT:

As mentioned by @Jerinaw in comment you can also use the below code, which is much shorter than above if you don't need support for < ie10

```
document.getElementById("projectsContent").classList.contains("animated") // class exists on element
```

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList classList has a method `contains`

Comment: @Jerinaw sorry I don't understand, can you elaborate.

Comment: Lets say you have an element. `element.classList.contains('animated')`. This will return true or false. `classList` is a list of all the classes on the element. `contains` is a method to check if the classList has the class you're looking for.

Comment: got ya, but it is no different from my answer, you will have to check for different classes separately. And it's support is limited in contrast of indexOf, only ie10+. Anyway, thanks for introducing to this api.

Comment: glad it helped :)

Comment: He didn't say what browser support was needed. Maybe it's better to mention the built in API and then a poly fill for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Use vanilla Javascript

```
document.querySelector('#aboutContent.myclass');
```

This reads: Select the element with the id (id selector #) `aboutContent`, and that has the class (class selector .) `myClass`.

Read up on
[CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)
[querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

I'd also like to note that you seem to be mixing vanilla javascript and jQuery. Maybe you should read up on selecting elements with [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: Is there a way to only select the class? Cause I have 3 ids that I need to check.

Comment: Select all elements with class "myclass" `document.querySelectorAll('.myclass');`